# Emptying bottles into a keg

Tags: beer, bottling, keg

I have about 3 gallons worth of IPA that are sitting in bottles.  I just got a new 5 gallon keg and I really want to use it.  Would it be a good idea to empty my bottles into the keg or is this something I should never do?

Thanks!

Comment: Brew more beer. :)

Comment: @Dustin: That should be an answer!  Also, it should probably be the answer to most brewing questions :)

Answer (score 10):

Is your IPA in the bottles any good? Is the carbonation OK? If so, then **do not do this**, or you risk ruining the beer.

Moving the beer from bottles to a keg introduces a great deal of oxygen into the beer, which will dramatically shorten the shelf life of the brew and possibly introduce off flavors pretty quickly.

Having said that, ***I actually did this exact thing 2 weeks ago.*** A friend of mine had a batch of pumpkin ale that never carbed in the bottle, so we carefully poured the bottles into a keg and charged it up. HOWEVER, the beer wasn't great (not sure if it was the base beer or the transfer to the keg) and I don't expect it to get any better, in fact, it will probably start getting worse.

Comment: You're spot on with the oxidation comment.  If you do attempt this, purge the keg of air first by hooking up your gas line to the OUT post of your keg.

Comment: I wish I knew what jacking up my beer was.

Comment: +1 on don't do it unless you're trying to rescue a beer.  "Jack up" means "mess up", I think.